# But, what is the greater baptism?

Tags: baptism

Jesus was baptized by John the Baptist, but proclaimed a greater baptism would be made available. What was that baptism of which He spoke?

Comment: Most Christians believe that Jesus was referring to the outpouring of the Holy Spirit on the Day of Pentecost detailed in Acts 2.

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] this to quote a specific verse?

Comment: While there could have been more substance to this question, I'm confused as to why it's been so heavily downvoted.

Comment: With the Baptism into the Breath. Then you can "Listen", and the "Truth" can come in your "Ears" and the "Light" (Understanding) will be inside of you. Then you will be forgiven. "so that ‘Seeing they may see and not perceive,
And hearing they may hear and not understand; Lest they should turn, And their sins be forgiven them.’”" (Mark 4:12)

Answer (score 4):

My understanding of the what you call the Greater Baptism is baptism via the Holy Spirit when you accept Christ as your savior. Water baptism and Spiritual baptism are two separate events.

NASB:

> [Matt 3:11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?st=2&utm_expid=13466113-11.5w1LoPJgSfySJpp2u36etw.2&search=Matthew%203%3A11&version=NASB&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.biblegateway.com%2Fpassage%2F%3Fst%3D2%26version%3DNIV%26search%3DMatthew%25203) “As for me, I baptize you <sup>[g]</sup>with water for repentance, but He who is coming after me is mightier than I, and I am not fit to remove His sandals; **He will baptize you** <sup>[h]</sup>**with the Holy Spirit and fire**. 12 His winnowing fork is in His hand, and He will thoroughly clear His threshing floor; and He will gather His wheat into the barn, but He will burn up the chaff with unquenchable fire.”
>
> <sup>g: Matthew 3:11 The Gr here can be translated in, with or by</sup>
> <sup>h: Matthew 3:11 The Gr here can be translated in, with or by</sup>